# Using Yii2 in yii1 project

Tags: yii, yii2

I am planning to migrate a very large and old yii1 project to yii2.
I read the [official docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-integration#using-both-yii2-yii1) how to load yii2 into yii1, read loads of similar  questions here.

But I still don't see how can I actually use the yii2 app.

Docs says:

> Now you can use most features provided by Yii. For example, you can create Active Record classes and use them to work with databases.

So is that means, I can use yii2 AR classes in yii1 ?

Can someone explain how ?
How would the structure of the app would look like - I need yii2 advanced.

Like (path): yii1/yii2/frontend and yii1/yii2/backend etc etc

One other thing, with Yii::$app, sure I can access some basic things
like request, user, db, but those are far not enough to migrate a big project

Comment: have you gone through [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-integration#using-both-yii2-yii1) section.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - yes, thanks, I even linked it in the question